# Looking for a product with a specific inn in a drow city

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, product-identification, drow

Our last play session with me as rotating DM ended with the party about to enter the (classic Greyhawk version) Vault of the Drow.  Currently, I am a player in another DM's game, but when it cycles back around to me, the party will indeed be entering and proceeding to the Black Tower.

Several weeks ago I read somewhere about an inn called something like the 'crowned cap' where Underdark foreigners and surface dwellers stay when they are in a certain drow city (I don't think the city was specifically Erelhei-Cinlu but don't remember).  There was, if I recall correctly, even a floor plan of the inn included in the source material.  Regardless of where it is from, I had planned to drop this inn into Erelhei-Cinlu and have the Bailiff of the Black Tower recommend the party stay there.

Unfortunately, in the time since reading it, I have lost reference to whatever source I found this in.  I know it is **not** in the original first edition D3 description of the city, nor in the third edition version presented in Dragon 298.  Neither is it in the third-party *Rise of the Drow*.  I am pretty sure the inn is not specifically tied to Erelhei-Cinlu, as it is not mentioned in the [greyhawkwiki](https://greyhawkonline.com/greyhawkwiki/Erelhei-Cinlu) for the city, so it is likely a generic 'drow city', but is possibly some version of Menzoberranzan.

Any help in identifying the source for my recollection of something like the 'crowned cap' inn would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this 3rd edition or newer, or could you be remembering 2nd edition content?

Comment: @From Unfortunately I have no idea of the edition.  However, the linked inn you suggest is pretty clearly a surface inn and serving things like elven wine would not go over well in the Underdark.  That's not the one I was looking for.  While the name may not be exactly crowned cap, it was definitely something relating to fungus.

Comment: The closest in name I can find is the Skull Cup, but there's no map and only a short description. Here's a near-complete list from 2009: http://candlekeep.com/forum/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=12088

Comment: @From Neither of those, but the candlekeep forum list is a fantastic resource.

Comment: Have you ever looked through *Drizzt Do'urden's Guide to the Underdark*?

Comment: @fectin I don't think so - unless I saw a section copy-pasted to an internet source.

Comment: You should probably close this question as it now seems OBE. Or if you found the answer (or a workable answer), answer it yourself and accept the answer.

Comment: @RedAnne I haven't found an answer yet.  Order of the British Empire?

Comment: @Kirt, LOL, nope, sorry, maybe a U.S. military thing: "overcome by events", i.e. no longer relevant, I mentioned this as you'd asked several months ago and it sounded like you needed this information fairly soon at that time.

Comment: @RedAnne Ah, understood. Right after I wrote my question we decided to move to 'the other game' (we rotate DMs / games; I am currently a player in ToA). Given the lack of answer, I have designed-forward so that I will not need the answer when we switch back to the Vault - but I would still like an answer before then, so will leave the question up at least until then.  However, my understanding of [meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11839/delete-an-unanswered-question-if-i-no-longer-need-the-answer) is that even if I no longer need the answer, if someone else might, it stays.